# How does portable class libraries, MVVM and DDD all work together?

Tags: mvvm, domain-driven-design, xamarin, portable-class-library, cqrs

So we are focusing on developing a enterprise web application that utilized DDD patterns with CQRS+ES. We have a pretty good handle on that from the enterprise level. Now when we want to open up our backend services to native mobile devices using Xamarin and portable class libraries how does this come together? Do we change our domain projects in each of our bounded context to be a PCL project type? What do we do with the MVVM side of things for instance in Windows Store App, Windows Phone app? Since we are pulling from a Web API service do we pull in the PCL bounded context library or do we make a subset domain model and a separate PCL library for our native client MVVM patterns?

Right now we are leaning towards leaving the original DDD projects as class libraries and just creating a separate portable class library for our MVVM code. We will probably use file linking to link back into the domain projects to get the models so that we always have the latest set of POCO objects and any DTO objects we want to use on the client. Any one else have any thoughts or ideas on this? I really don't see a lot of discussions around this DDD+PCL combination.

Comment: @JohnOsborne this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Thanks for the link @gnat

Comment: What an awesome question. Surprising to see there aren't other similar ones in this area.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of thinking about this and what i did to put Xamarin in my current architecture with DDD approach was:

1. Put your Domain Entities in a PCL project and use it to reference in all projects that you need, such as Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, ASP.NET, WCF, etc.
2. Your Domain Services can be in a normal class library that will be used for the Application layer. The application layer will be used by the Presentation projects such as ASP.NET MVC.
3. In the Distributed Services layer you're going to expose your services for Xamarin or other apps to communicate with your application. You can use ASP.NET Web Api or WCF with REST. This layer will also use the application layer respecting the DDD concepts.
4. The xamarin projects go in the presentation layer but do not use application layer. Here you will write your services for Xamarin to connect to your Distributed Services Layer through the internet. If you need offline sync you can also put that in here. Here you're going to reference your Domain Entities Project and have all your entities with their business rules.

This way you have your domain and business rules shared with all your solution and respecting DDD concepts and role separation.